# Non regex variant of dired-do-find-regexp-and-replace

Tags: dired

Dired has the interactive function `dired-do-find-regexp-and-replace` which can be match based on the regexp you have passed and perform the replace.

But I'm looking for non regex variant of `dired-do-find-regexp-and-replace` where I don't have to pass the regexp. Is something like that available for dired ? I'm okay with using additional dired based packages for it, if they provide the non-regexp version of the function.

Comment: Please be more specific, if possible with an example. How it's supposed to match something you don't pass?

Comment: @Muihlinn I can see how the question is confusing. I have edited it. Does that make it better ?

Comment: Pass a literal string as regexp, you'll just have to look for chars that can match a regexp operator.

Comment: @Muihlinn But my literal string has regex characters in it (and I don't want to escape them).

Comment: Now that I've given an answer it feels like a duplicate I cannot find.

Comment: Both Q&A look good to me. Searching for "regexp-quote" doesn't suggest that the question is a duplicate or that answers elsewhere involving `regexp-quote` are relevant here.

Answer (score 2):

Use `dired-do-find-regexp-and-replace` but making use of `regexp-quote` to match only the literal string of its argument. This way you'll use the quoted regexp only as search string, without touching the original.

```lisp
(dired-do-find-regexp-and-replace (regexp-quote from) to)
```