# More simple approach to replace some text in many files?

Tags: replace, query-replace

Linux Mint 20.2

Emacs 27.1

Task:

I has folder with `MyProject` with `5 subfolders`.

Total count of files in all this folders are about 500 files.

I need all files that content

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
```

replace by line:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
```

To do I use the next steps:

```
 M-x "find-name-dired" - you will be prompted for a root directory and a filename pattern.
 Press "t" to "toggle mark" for all files found.
 Press "Q" for text to search: "import org.apache.log4j.Logger;"and replace by "import org.slf4j.Logger;"  
 Proceed as with query-replace-regexp: SPACE to replace and move to next match, n to skip a match, etc.
 Press "C-x s" and then choose "!" for saving all buffers.
```

OK, this work... but **so many steps**. Maybe has more simple approach to replace some text in many files?

Comment: I take it that the main problem is step 4, where you are doing query-replaces on each file that matches. The others are all short. There may be a way to replace the interactive query replace with a batch one, but personally, I'd write a shell script to do all that and test it on a backup copy of the original directory, diffing against the original directory to make sure that the changes are what I expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with `wgrep`, which you can install from Melpa.

The workflow would be:

1. Call grep: `M-x grep`
2. Fill in an invocation that will match your files and patterns:
   `grep --color=auto -nH --null -e 'import org.apache.log4j.Logger;' ./*`
   (note that the first part is the default, you only need to enter `'import org.apache.log4f.Logger;'./*`
3. The results are presented in a `*grep*` buffer
4. Make the buffer editable: `C-c C-p`.
5. Query-replace/`M-%`, and enter your search and replace patterns
6. hit `!` to instantly replace all matches in the buffer
7. `C-c C-e` to make those changes in each of the files you searched

This is still a lot of steps, but it would save you pressing space for every match, or `!` for every file.

Alternatively, you could do this from the command line with `sed`:

```sh
sed -i s/import org.apache.log4j.Logger;/import org.slf4j.Logger;/g ./path/to/files/*txt
```

Comment: I use "rgrep" because I need to replace in many files in current folder and all subfolders.

Comment: @a_subscriber You could also use [`elgrep`](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/elgrep). There you have `elgrep-menu` that opens a menu for all the available settings. That menu also offers a toggle for recursive search. Editing the `elgrep`-buffer with the search results is simple. `C-e` enters the edit mode. You do your changes, e.g., with `query-replace` as suggested here and then you save the `elgrep`-buffer with `save-buffer` bound to `C-x C-s` as you are used to. This saves the changes in the respective files.
**AND:** `elgrep` [offers much more](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/elgrep).

Answer (score 1):

This is trivial in a Dired buffer for the directory possibly containing (possibly with subdirs, recursively) matches for some search pattern.

Just use **`Q`**, which is bound to `dired-do-find-regexp-and-replace`:

> **`Q`** runs the command `dired-do-find-regexp-and-replace` (found in
> `dired-mode-map`), which is an interactive autoloaded compiled Lisp
> function in `dired-aux.el`.
>
> It is bound to `Q`, `<menu-bar> <operate> <query-replace>`.
>
> `(dired-do-find-regexp-and-replace FROM TO &optional ARG INTERACTIVEP)`
>
> Replace matches of `FROM` with `TO`, in all marked files.
>
> If no files are marked, use the file under point.
>
> For any marked directory, matches in all of its files are replaced,
> recursively.  However, files matching `grep-find-ignored-files`
> and subdirectories matching `grep-find-ignored-directories` are skipped
> in the marked directories.
>
> `REGEXP` should use constructs supported by your local `grep` command.

See also [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/58900/105), about replacing literal matches.

Comment: The problem is after success executed "dired-do-find-regexp-and-replace" I need to press MANY TIMES "!" to save every files. It's not very convenient.

Comment: This is what I thought at first too. It would be good if `dired-do-find-regexp-and-replace` provided a 'super-!', to let the user instantly complete the replacement for every file in the set, and not have to press it once for each file. Maybe this exists, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: @Tyler: Yep, you're right. And the same is true of the alternative command (what `Q` used to be bound to), `dired-do-query-replace-regexp`. You could code a command that does what you want, but I don't know of a predefined command that does it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use library [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) then you can use command `diredp-do-eval-in-marked-recursive` to do what you want.

If you use it directly it asks you for a sexp to evaluate at the beginning of each file to be acted on.  In this case, the sexp you want is just a `replace-string` sexp.

So this simple command does the job:

```lisp
(defun bar ()
  (interactive)
  (diredp-do-eval-in-marked-recursive
   '(replace-string "import org.apache.log4j.Logger;"
                    "import org.slf4j.Logger;")))
```

Command `diredp-do-eval-in-marked-recursive` is bound by default to key sequence **`M-+ @ M-:`**. It's also on menu-bar menu **Multiple** > **Marked Here and Below** > **Apply (Map)** > **Eval Sexp In**.

> **`diredp-do-eval-in-marked-recursive`** is an interactive Lisp function in
> [`dired+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired%2b.el).
>
> `(diredp-do-eval-in-marked-recursive SEXP &optional IGNORE-MARKS-P DETAILS)`
>
> Evaluate `SEXP` in each of the marked files, including in marked subdirs.
>
> Like `diredp-do-eval-in-marked` but act recursively on subdirs, and do
> no result-logging, error-logging, or echoing.
>
> The files included are those that are marked in the current Dired
> buffer, or all files in the directory if none are marked.  Marked
> subdirectories are handled recursively in the same way.
>
> With a prefix argument, ignore all marks - include all files in this
> Dired buffer and all subdirs, recursively.
>
> When called from Lisp, optional arg `DETAILS` is passed to
> `diredp-get-files`.

*[All of the Dired+ commands that act on marked files not only in the current Dired buffer but also in Dired buffers for any subdirs in that buffer that are themselves marked, and so on, recursively, are on prefix key **`M-+`**. Those that apply a function, evaluate a sexp, or invoke a command are on prefix key **`M-+ @`**. And `M-:` is mnemonic for evaluating a sexp. (The same is true of the non-"recursive" commands - same key bindings, but without the `M-+`.)]*

Answer (score 0):

This may actually be easier on the command line with perl than within emacs:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/import org.apache.log4j.Logger;/import org.apache.log4j.Logger;/;' * */*
```

(Add more `*/*/*` if you have deeper subfolders.)

Added advantage: backup copies of your original files are created with the suffix ".bak".

Comment: Combine it with `find` if you want to select *some* files to operate on, instead of operating on every file.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, no answer was given yet to make use of `-batch` Emacs mode that has been created for situations like this. So here's a simple example:

```python
$ echo "import org.apache.log4j.Logger;" > 1 && cp 1 2 && cp 1 3
$ emacs -batch --eval '(progn (dolist (file command-line-args-left) (find-file file) (replace-regexp "apache.log4j" "slf4j") (save-buffer) (kill-buffer)))' ./1 ./2 ./3
Mark set
Replaced 1 occurrence
Mark set
Replaced 1 occurrence
Mark set
Replaced 1 occurrence
$ grep "" ./1 ./2 ./3
./1:import org.slf4j.Logger;
./2:import org.slf4j.Logger;
./3:import org.slf4j.Logger;
```

---

Worth noting separately that if your replacement does not fit into a small one-liner you can also save it to a file like this:

```lisp
$ cat my_replace.el
(dolist (file command-line-args-left)
  (find-file file)
  (replace-regexp "apache.log4j" "slf4j")
  (save-buffer)
  (kill-buffer))
$ emacs -batch -l my_replace.el ./1 ./2 ./3
Mark set
Replaced 1 occurrence
Mark set
Replaced 1 occurrence
Mark set
Replaced 1 occurrence
```